# iOS MPMediaItem: Options as set in iTunes

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, avasset, mpmediaitem

When loading MPMediaItems via the MPMediaLibrary (MediaPlayer Framework), I'm looking for a way to access the `start`, `stop`, and `volume` properties as they can be set in iTunes via right click on a song => `Get Info` => `Options`.

These properties are not properties of MPMediaItem, and I'm not (yet?) able to access them via AVAsset either.

When playing the MPMediaItem using the `MPMusicPlayerController` applicationMusicPlayer, it does play the track from the set start point. However I need to use `AVAudioPlayer` and would therefore like to find a way to fetch these settings programmatically.

Any help or hints would be much appreciated!

Comment: I would love to try to answer this question, but I'd need to sync an iOS device with iTunes, which is a profoundly painful operation. Modifying options in iTunes doesn't affect the file modification date, so it's iTunes metadata which makes me doubt that it would be available from `AVAsset` (guessing iTunes song ~ `MPMediaItem`, file ~ `AVAsset`). That said, have you looked at the `AVAsset` metadata properties?

Comment: I have looked in AVAsset, but can not find properties that match what I need. I'm not syncing with iTunes directly, but via iCloud Music Library. This does sync everything with iTunes such as track notes and start/end times.